Register custom protocol handler in Firefox (open application from link in PDF)
I would like to open hyperlinks to an external application from a PDF inside Firefox, e.g:
zotero://select/library/items/3DKDWDRD

However, these links are not clickable from the PDF within Firefox (in contrast to other browsers such as Safari, Chrome).
When entering the link manually, it opens the external application.
When inspecting the PDF with the HTML inspector, the element shows up like this:
<section data-annotation-id="714R" tabindex="1000" style="z-index: 0; left: 27.0271%; top: 24.0591%; width: 10.0752%; height: 1.65675%;" class="linkAnnotation" id="pdfjs_internal_id_714R"></section>

A clickable link that does work (https://) looks like this:
<section data-annotation-id="714R" tabindex="1000" style="z-index: 0; left: 27.0271%; top: 24.0591%; width: 10.0752%; height: 1.65675%;" class="linkAnnotation">
    <a data-element-id="714R" title="https://doi.org/10.1007/s11244-009-9251-z" href="https://doi.org/10.1007/s11244-009-9251-z" target="" rel="noopener noreferrer nofollow" id="pdfjs_internal_id_714R"></a>
</section>

In Firefox (132.0.2 on macOS), custom protocol handlers are apparently not supported.
I've read that allowed protocols appear in some sort of hardcoded whitelist, but I've no idea where to find this.
In about:config, I already tried the following without success:
"network.protocol-handler.app.zotero": "/Applications/Zotero.app/Contents/MacOS/zotero", # this seems superfluous, since the link works manually
"network.protocol-handler.expose.zotero": false,
"network.protocol-handler.external.zotero": true

Is there any way to allow such external protocols in Firefox??
